# How to log full http header with jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm setting up a Jmeter performance test case and in the debugging phase I need to log the full HTTP headers.

I have created my jmx script for a test.

I can't find anywhere how to tell Jmeter to log that to the ouput in jmeter/log.

Is it possible and how ?

Comment: Why is view result tree listener not sufficient for debugging? It shows full request/response including headers for every single request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In the JMeter workflow, it is usually the easiest to use the GUI to create and debug your test. The [View Results Tree listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View%5FResults%5FTree) shows a tree of all your requests and responses, including header information. It should be mentioned, even though it is called out in a red box at that link, do NOT use the view results tree listener during a load test, it is a very expensive component that drains memory and CPU.
2. To debug from the command line, the [save responses to a file](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener is the usual go-to to save response data to disk, but I'm not certain it saves headers. The [Simple Data Writer listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) though does both Request and Response Headers via the configure panel.

[image]

Again, care should be taken to not leave in excessive logging for a full load test, your disk I/O could become a bottleneck.

3. And last, as with most things JMeter, you can replicate any behavior in a beanshell component. Either a post processor or an assertion.

   ```
   if (someCondition) {
       log.info(ResponseHeaders);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks I was finally using the solution (2) after struggling with the jmeter documentation which doesn't cover the jmx part but only the gui part. Strange...